# display timer countdown according to attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, ajax, product-view, date

right now i am displaying same countdown timer by default in all product view pages using below code.  but i need different countdown timers in every product pages according to value we set for the attribute.

using custom module , we set **Date & time** for the attribute : `ecomdev_expiry_date`

as `May 11 2016 - 12 : 15: 15`

[image]

if current date & time is `May 10 2016 - 12 : 15: 15` , than in view page i want to display

Time left to Buy : **24: 00: 00** and it should keep on updating as **23 : 59: 59** , **23: 59, 58** so on as like :

[image]

**phtml**

```
<?php 

$end_datetime='2016/06/10 12:15:15';

$date =  date( "Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($end_datetime));   
$endstr= date(strtotime($date));

$nowstr = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$now =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $nowstr); ?>

<span id="countdown" class"countdown">
<script>showtiming('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>')</script>
</span>
```

**script**

```
<script>

 function showtiming(dt,no)
{

 var end = new Date(dt);
 var now_date= new Date(no);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
      flag_time = true;
    timer = '';
    setInterval(function(){showRemaining();},1000);

    function showRemaining() 
    {
        var date = no;
                var now = new Date(date);
                var de= now.getTime();

                if ( flag_time ) {
                timer = de;
                }
                var d = new Date(timer);
                currentYear = d.getFullYear();
                month = d.getMonth()+1;

                var currentDate = d.getDate();
                currentDate = currentDate < 10 ? '0'+currentDate : currentDate;

                var hours = d.getHours();
                var minutes = d.getMinutes();
                var seconds = d.getSeconds();

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
                var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes+ ':' + seconds; 
                timer = timer + 1000;
               var now_time = currentYear+'/' + month+'/' + currentDate + ' ' + strTime ;


        var now = new Date(now_time);

        var distance = end - now;

        if (distance < 0) {
             if (distance>-3) 
                {
                    location.reload(true); 
                    return;
                };

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Completed';


            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
       if (days <10)
        {days = '0' + days;}
    if (hours <10)
        {hours = '0' + hours;}
    if (minutes < 10)
       { minutes = '0' + minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10)
        {seconds = '0' + seconds; }
    if(days==00)
    {
                    dytext = '';   

    }
    else if(days==1)
    {
        dytext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ days +' Day  </span>';   
    }
    else
    {
         dytext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ days +' Days  </span>';    
    }
    if(hours==00) {
        hrtext='';
    }
    else {
        hrtext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ hours + '</span>'+ ":";
    }
    if(minutes==00)
    {
        mintext='';
    }else {
              mintext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ minutes +'</span>'+ ":";

    }
        sectext = '<span class="countdown-text">'+ seconds +'</span>';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = dytext + hrtext +  mintext + sectext;
       flag_time = false;
    }


}

</script>

<script> showtiming('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>') </script>
```

Comment: `$end_datetime=$_product->geteComdevExpiryDate();` check this showing the correct values?

Comment: @QaisarSatti now it showing "completed" text for all pages : [link1](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/fashion-lady-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)  [link2](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/butterfly-love-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) . please click on link 2nd time.

Comment: echo `$_product->geteComdevExpiryDate();` and tell me what the output of that

Comment: its not displaying any value

Comment: i added the code above : `<?php $end_datetime=$_product->geteComdevExpiryDate();`

Comment: `print_r($_product->getData());` this will show your attribute value?

Comment: its displaying lot of values now, please visit [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/butterfly-love-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) 2nd time.

Comment: this is showing `May 11, 2017 11:13:00 AM` that is your value?

Comment: yes, you are right... thats is value we set for one product.

Comment: add like this  `<?php $end_datetime=$_product->getEcomdevExpiryDate();  ?>`

Comment: i added, please check link

Comment: working fine for particular product and for all other products it showing : `completed` on top i need to hide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line in js `document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Completed';`

and add date like `<?php $end_datetime=$_product->getEcomdevExpiryDate(); ?>`